# How do I display the user's location with a marker in gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails, rails-3.1

I have been trying to get a custom use of gmaps4rails running, and I have the code set to display my string of json coordinates on the map, and the center on user IS working, I can zoom into my location from home, work and my phone. I just cannot get the js right to display an 'Im here' button on the map once permission is given.

here is the code I use for the map from gmaps4rails:

```
<%= gmaps(:map_options => {:detect_location => true, :center_on_user => true, :auto_zoom => false, :zoom => 12, :auto_adjust => true}, :markers => {:data => @json} ) %>
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT Dec.6 after answer:

I am adding in the code for the callback as so:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
          Gmaps.map.createMarker({Lat: Gmaps.map.userLocation.lat(),
                                  Lng: Gmaps.map.userLocation.lng(), 
                                  rich_marker: null, 
                                  marker_picture: "http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/1.0/images/heart30.png"
                   })
                }
        </script>
```

and still not getting a response on the map. Is this a problem with my js coding? I'm not pro yet.

thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your question

Comment: @apneadiving THanks for reading it, I will rephrase: Trying to display a marker for the Gmaps4rails.map.userLocation data. Currently the map will center on user, but does not display a marker. ie: like at a mall/airport the "You are Here" arrow. hope that helps?

Comment: ok gotcha, don't forget to accept the answer (new user notice)

Comment: updated the question with current code and not sure what's going on now. thanks so much for putting up with this!

Comment: I think I understand why: userLocation isn't available when the callback is triggered because it has an unpredictable delay. You should use `setInterval` to loop until it's filled (of course, use `clearInterval` once done)

Comment: What was the final code for this? I'm trying to do something similar to add a marker with current location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Gmaps.map.createMarker({Lat: Gmaps.map.userLocation.lat(),
                        Lng: Gmaps.map.userLocation.lng(), 
                        rich_marker: null, 
                        marker_picture: ""
                       })
```

in the callback.

---

Notice you can pass the url of your desired marker.

BTW, you should create an issue on github if you feel like this is a useful feature.

Comment: Will give this a shot! Thanks! and to save your github issue list, will see if people traffic this Q first before listing?